# Is there an easier way to "combine" stuff in Everquest?

Tags: everquest

*This question actually comes from my mother, an avid EQ player*

Is there a macro / addon / something to make combining items for tradeskills easier? By default, combining items requires clicking around a lot and putting things in the inventory. Is there anything available to ease the annoying bits?

Answer (score 6):

You only need to move items from your inventory into the tradeskill container until you have successfully created your first item and learned the recipe. (Note: some recipes are pre-learned by scribing a scroll or book - this is more common for cultural recipes than other types).

After you learn a recipe,  open the tradeskill container in recipe mode using Ctrl+right-click instead of the usual right-click. You can now search for recipes by name and/or skill range. Click on a recipe and it shows up in the virtual-container section of the window.

Item icons with a red overlay are items you don't have in your inventory. Item icons with a green overlay are items you have in your inventory.

Once all of the item overlays are green, click the Combine button. If you successfully create an item, click the Inventory button to put the item in your inventory.

You can also add recipes to a favorites page and then show the favorites page later instead of having to search every time.

Answer (score 5):

The "default" method is the only approved method. EverQuest does not provide any facility for addons, and also explicitly prohibits their use. They go as far as to monitor player's process task list. The following is from the [EQ Terms of Service](http://help.station.sony.com/cgi-bin/soe.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=15630):

> D. CONSENT TO MONITOR
>
> Please note that some games available on or through The Station may, when in operation, monitor your computer's random access memory, MAC address, and system and configuration files, crash data, etc. for the purpose of monitoring [..] and also for the purpose of identifying unauthorized third party programs running concurrently with your game which, in SOE's sole determination: (i) enable or facilitate cheating of any type; (ii) allow users to modify or hack the applicable game interface, environment, and/or experience in any way not expressly authorized by SOE; or (iii) intercept, "mine" or otherwise collect information from or through the applicable game (an "Unauthorized Third Party Program"). In the event that a game detects an Unauthorized Third Party Program, (a) the game may communicate information back to SOE, including without limitation your Station Account username, details about the Unauthorized Third Party Program detected and the activities or functions performed thereby, and/or details about your computer, and/or (b) SOE may exercise any or all of its rights and remedies under this Agreement or the applicable game end user license agreement without prior notice to the user linked to such Unauthorized Third Party Program.

Answer (score 2):

As [Brian noted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17680/is-there-an-easier-way-to-combine-stuff-in-everquest/18076#18076), modifying EverQuest or using macros is a violation of the EULA, and is liable to get you banned.

*However*, with that in mind, [MacroQuest 2](http://www.macroquest2.com/wiki/index.php/MacroQuest2:Intro) will do what you want to do, but because of its issue with the EULA, it's not for the faint of heart to get running. The wiki describes what you need to do.

Once you have MacroQuest 2 running, you can use [QuickCombineV2.mac](http://www.macroquest2.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=16919) to do what you're looking to do.